# Complex query consisting 3 tables using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 3 tables:

- student
- internship
- student_internship

```
create table student(student_id varchar(45), student_name varchar(45));
create table internship(internship_id varchar(45), internship_name varchar(45));
```

and student_intership is the 'bridge' of the two tables.

```
student_intership(student_id, internship_id)
```

So, it is a many to many situation.

Situation:

I want to get the name of the internship and number of student, but
if there's no student for that internship, so it should have the following example:

```
 intership_name | count(student_id)
--------------------------------
 1. intern1        |  20
 2. intern2        |  3
 3. intern3        |  0
```

the code i have tried:

```
select internship.internship_id, count(student.student_id)
from student_internship, internship, student
where student_internship.student_id = student.student_id
and student_internship.internship_id = internship.internship_id
group by student_internship.internship_id;
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You're probably going to need a `LEFT JOIN` in there somewhere.

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes i tried, and i can get the first 2 line...i have problem with the 3rd line, i cant get 0 for intern3 as there are no student related to intern3

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: @RocketHazmat i edit the question. pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT i.internship_name, COALESCE(COUNT(si.student_id), 0) AS cnt
FROM internship i
LEFT JOIN student_intership si ON i.internship_id = si.internship_id
GROUP BY si.internship_id, i.internship_name
```

The above query will return *all* records of table `internship`. It will return `0` for `internship` records having no relation to `student` records.

Comment: Why do you need to group by `i.internship_name`?  Wouldn't `GROUP BY si.internship_id` suffice?

Comment: @RocketHazmat In the newest version of MySQL (5.7.5) all non-aggregated columns present in the `SELECT` clause of the query have to appear in the `GROUP BY` clause (See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)).

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos why is the student table is not required in the query? i mean, how to know if the table is required in the query or not? because i got other complex queries involving 6 tables, and i would like to learn it...can you teach me?

Comment: @Wilz5363: The `student` table isn't needed because your `student_intership` table contains all the info you need.  It has which students are in which internship.  The student table just contains student names and no internship info.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos thanks your help too. This gives me the idea and i was able to solve my other problems as well. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Quick stab:

```
 SELECT st.student_id
    ,st.student_name
    ,si.InternshipCount
FROM student st
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) AS InternshipCount
        ,student_id
    FROM student_internship s
    INNER JOIN internship i
        ON s.student_id = i.student_id
        group by student_id
    ) AS si
    ON st.student_id = si.student_id
```